# python read csv file with row and column headers into dictionary with two keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have csv file of the following format,

```
,col1,col2,col3
row1,23,42,77
row2,25,39,87
row3,48,67,53
row4,14,48,66
```

I need to read this into a dictionary of two keys such that

```
dict1['row1']['col2'] = 42
dict1['row4']['col3'] = 66
```

If I try to use [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) with default options

```
with open(filePath, "rb" ) as theFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(theFile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
    print line
```

I get the following output

```
{'': 'row1', 'col2': '42', 'col3': '77', 'col1': '23'}
{'': 'row2', 'col2': '39', 'col3': '87', 'col1': '25'}
{'': 'row3', 'col2': '67', 'col3': '53', 'col1': '48'}
{'': 'row4', 'col2': '48', 'col3': '66', 'col1': '14'}
```

I'm not sure of how to process this output to create the type of dictionary that I'm interested in.

For sake of completeness, it would also help if you can address how to write back the dictionary into a csv file with the above format

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the CSV module:

```
import csv
dict1 = {}

with open("test.csv", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    headers = next(reader)[1:]
    for row in reader:
        dict1[row[0]] = {key: int(value) for key, value in zip(headers, row[1:])}
```

Comment: I have one issue, the values in the dict are strings and not integers. How can I ensure that the values in the dictionary are integers

Comment: See my edit - just call `int()` on each value; however, this will fail if even a single value can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: For the sake of completeness can you also describe how to write back the dictionary into a csv file in the above format. I have edited my question that would warrant such a response.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) for that even if it is a bit an overkill. The pro is that there is almost nothing to code to obtain the expected result.

```
# Reading the file
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', index_col=0)

# Creating the dict
d = df.transpose().to_dict(orient='series')

print(d['row1']['col2'])
42
```

Comment: This answer is elegant. Unfortunately I'm working on server where Pandas is not present. I prefer not to modify any python setting at moment, since it could break the other packages of interest.

Answer (score 3):

The format of the input file is not exactly convenient to parse with `csv` module. I'd parse headers separately, then parse the rest line by line, splitting by `,`, stripping and making dictionaries along the way. The working code:

```
from pprint import pprint

d = {}
with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    headers = [header.strip() for header in next(f).split(",")[1:]]

    for line in f:
        values = [value.strip() for value in line.split(",")]
        d[values[0]] = dict(zip(headers, values[1:]))

pprint(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'row1': {'col1': '23', 'col2': '42', 'col3': '77'},
 'row2': {'col1': '25', 'col2': '39', 'col3': '87'},
 'row3': {'col1': '48', 'col2': '67', 'col3': '53'},
 'row4': {'col1': '14', 'col2': '48', 'col3': '66'}}
```