# csv data to multiple dictionaries in array

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file in this format

```
name value domain
n1   v1    d1
n2   v2    d2
n3   v3    d3
```

How can I get this array out of the file:

```
[{'name': 'n1', 'value': 'v1', 'domain': 'd1'},
 {'name': 'n2', 'value': 'v2', 'domain': 'd2'},
 {'name': 'n3', 'value': 'v3', 'domain': 'd3'}]
```

Can I do it without pandas?

What I've tried:

```
with open("cookies.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        dict_reader = DictReader(f)
        list_of_dicts = list(dict_reader)
return list_of_dicts
```

And got this result:

```
[{'name;value;domain': 'n1;v1;d1'}, 
 {'name;value;domain': 'n2;v2;d2'}, 
 {'name;value;domain': 'n3;v3;d3'}]
```

Comment: Your file example doesn't look like it is CSV. CSV is supposed to be comma separated values

Comment: Check the below link which is of similar question     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829360/python-read-csv-file-with-row-and-column-headers-into-dictionary-with-two-keys